# WebSockets. How to correctly send back message from server to browser

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

After handshakes, I send to server some "Hello".

```
#Chrome javascript console

~var s = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8999');
 s.onmessage = function(t){alert(t)};
 s.onopen = function(){console.log('yes');}

~sock.send('Hello');
```

Than server try to read this message and send back another

```
`#server.py`
....
text = client.recv(1024)
client.send('hello from server')
```

But js console give me error

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8999/' failed: Invalid frame header

**UPDATE**

Here my server file

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 9999))
sock.listen(5)

import hashlib
import base64

def makeHash(key):
    hash0 = key.replace(" ","")+"258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
        return hash0
handshaken = False

print("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 9999")

import sys

data = ''
header = ''

client, address = sock.accept()
while True:
    if not handshaken:
        data = client.recv(16).decode("utf-8");
        header+=data
        if header.find('\r\n\r\n')>=0:
            key = header.split('Sec-WebSocket-Key: ')[1].split('\r\n')[0]
            hash0 = makeHash(key).encode('utf-8')
            hash1 = hashlib.sha1(hash0)
            ready = base64.b64encode(hash1.digest())
            newKey = str(ready)[2:][:-1]
            answer = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"+"Upgrade:         websocket\r\n"+"Connection: Upgrade\r\n"+"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "+newKey+"\r\n\r\n"
        client.send(answer.encode('utf-8'))
        handshaken = True

    else:
        print("-")
else:
    tmp = client.recv(1024)
    data = str(tmp);
    print(data)

    answ = ('Hello').encode('utf-8')
    client.send(answ)
```

Comment: What is client? What websocket functionality are you using in the Python code. If it's just a plain socket you'll need more code than that.

Comment: sipmle sockets.
I mean `import socket`

Comment: Look for something online to show you how to do the websocket stuff in Python e.g. http://popdevelop.com/2010/03/a-minimal-python-websocket-server/  disclaimer I didn't try it but it should give you the basics.

Comment: A webSocket is NOT just a plain TCP socket.  You can't just send your message in plain text.  It's a whole handshake upon connection, protocol, security scheme and data frame format.  You have to use the exact webSocket protocol in order to talk to a webSocket connection.  There are many existing libraries that already implement the webSocket protocol for pretty much all languages, so you can certainly find one for python.